# Obtener el id de un usuario en un listView y a partir de ese id poder hacer modificaciones en sus atributos en otro intent

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-listview

Tengo una List view en la que se muestran los usuarios creados previamente y cuando hago click en algun elemento de la list view, se me abre otro intent en el que quiero poder modificar un atributo de ese mismo usuario.
Este es el código del onclick en la lista, que en teoría me coge el id del usuario en el que haces click.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent  intentJuego = new Intent(this, Buscaminas.class);
    startActivity(intentJuego);
}
```

Para modificar el usuario uso:

```
public void modificarPuntuacion(Amigo amigo, int puntuacion, long id1){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constantes.PUNTUACION, puntuacion);

    String[] argumentos = new String[]{String.valueOf(id1)};
    db.update(Constantes.TABLA_AMIGOS, values, "id = id1", argumentos);
    db.close();
}
```

Y ahora en el intent que se abre al clickar sobre el usuario de la lista, no sé como obtener el id que te coge para poder modificar ese usuario.

Comment: Tu adapter se llena a partir de objetos usuario? si es así agregalo a tu pregunta.